# Autofill default username in Windows 10 login screen

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Is there a way for Windows 10 to set up a default user login name to be filled during the interactive logon and screen unlock after the CTRL+ALT+DEL?

Of course this would be just the login name, not the password. During a recent update, my username tripled in length, so I would definitely prefer if I were not required to type it every time again and again.

Comment: It does autofill the last username.  Unless you have policies from your organization/domain specifically blocking that.